# Lubuntu wifi error: internet disconnected

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, internet

I installed Lubuntu on my Compaq mini laptop 1 year ago and it always worked fine.

Then I dowloaded some recommended updates 3 days ago and after these updates my WiFi stopped working.

I get the following error: "You are not connected to the Internet" (translated from the language on-screen). The wired connection is working fine and I've re-installed my Broadcom driver but no effect, it is saying the driver is working fine.

*Do you know how to fix this?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Katarina, please follow the above link.  It is the best resource we have available on this site to solve all Broadcom issues.  Take your time reading through the solutions and follow them exactly.  **No need to reinstall your laptop** as the exact update would break the exact same thing again...

Comment: Hi Fabby, thanks! I´ll check the link. I hope some of those tips will be working. I´ll let you know. :)

Comment: I'm back! It's working again! :) I removed sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source and installed b43-fwcutter & firmware-b43-lpphy-installerer. Thanks guys!! You're good! :) Fabby & @Web-E –